# Getting 405 MethodNotAllowed after upgrade to .Net Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.2

- ASP.Net Core 2.2
- Visual Studio 2019 Professional

Run integration tests against the controller after upgrading .Net Core from 2.1 to 2.2

While running test case for URL that doesn't exist on the controller I'm getting 405 MethodNotAllowed.

I expect to get status code 404 (as before the upgrade to 2.2) but getting 405 MethodNotAllowed.

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Authorize(Policy = Constants.APIPolicies.OrgId)]
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
[Route("api/patient")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class PatientController : Controller {
        ...
        ...

        [Audit(Constants.AuditParameters.PatientUidRoot)]
        [HttpPost("v1/{" + Constants.RouteParams.orgId + "}/ResolvePatientId")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPatientIdByUID([FromRoute] Guid orgId, [FromBody] UidModel patientUid)
        {
            ...
        }

        ...
        ...
}
```

Test:

```
patientUid = new UID(validRoot, validExtension);
response = await _mApiHostFixture.Client.PostAsync(string.Format("/api/patient/v1/{0}/ResolvePatientIdxx", orgId), new JsonContent(patientUid));
response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

Comment: Can you share your controller code and test?